Calculate calender days between two dates in java
is there any way to calculate calendar days between two dates. I tried with  below code but looks like it gives 1 day as answer. But I am expecting the difference between this date is 2 days. No need to consider the hours/minutes/seconds. For e.g in the below code 01-06-2023 is one day and 02-06-2023 is another day so the difference should be 2 days.
        LocalDateTime startLdt = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-01T00:00");
        LocalDateTime endLdt   = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-02T23:59");
        
        LocalDate startdt = LocalDate.parse("2023-06-01");
        LocalDate enddt   = LocalDate.parse("2023-06-02");

        long diffInDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startLdt, endLdt);        
        long noOfDaysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startdt, enddt);

        System.out.println(diffInDays);  //1
        System.out.println(noOfDaysBetween);  //1

correct me in case if there is any issues in my understanding of Calender days.

"But I wanted to consider the eliminated 23 hour 59 minutes as a day" - are they? Where's the limit about how you determine the length of a day? Maybe adding one minute and then calculate the difference could help?

Its calender days. Even if it is not covered 24 hours I wanted to count a day.

I would assume that only full days, and not started days, are counted properly.  Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Would a difference of 1 days and 1 minute already yield 2 calendar days?

just updated the questions. yes it is Days count.

So just call .toLocalDate() before passing the dates to between then add 1 to the result if you prefer? Am I missing something?

Sounds like you just need to +1 to your code as it is

Don‘t use 23:59 to signify the end of the day. It is not. If you need the date and time of the end of the day, use 00:00 the following day (so 2023-06-03T00:00). This will also get you the expected day count (2).

But be aware that the day does not start at 00:00 on all days in all time zones, and may not go all the way to 24:00 exclusive. If the day starts at 01:00 and you count days until 00:00 some future date, you will be sure to miss 1 day again. So you probably should not use the time component in this calculation at all.

You should just add 1 to the result that ChronoUnit.DAYS.between gives you.
If you are working with LocalDateTimes, you should convert them to LocalDates first, since you only care about the date part.
LocalDateTime startLdt = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-01T05:00");
LocalDateTime endLdt   = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-02T00:00");

LocalDate startdt = LocalDate.parse("2023-06-01");
LocalDate enddt   = LocalDate.parse("2023-06-02");

long localDateTimeResult = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startLdt.toLocalDate(), endLdt.toLocalDate()) + 1;
long localDateResult = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startdt, enddt) + 1;

System.out.println(localDateTimeResult); // 2
System.out.println(localDateResult); // 2


I will get expected result. But is this is the right method. Any other utilities available in java which gives the same result. Any methods in Calender or GregorianCalender class which gives a day count without considering the time parameter.

@JAVA_CAT I'm not sure what you mean by "right method", but there is also startdt.until(enddt, ChronoUnit.DAYS) which does exactly the same thing, so you also need to add 1. I would suggest staying away from Calendar/GregorianCalendar because their APIs are quite bad compared to java.time ones.

Your approach is fine but like just about every other range in Java, they go from inclusive to exclusive. Here is the method signature from the JavaDoc for ChronoUnit#between

public long between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive,
Temporal temporal2Exclusive)

So the end objects, in this case the end dates, are excluded from the computation. That means you need to add 1 as Sweeper said.
In these cases I prefer to update the exclusive object by one unit of the appropriate type.  In your example, it would be as follows:
LocalDateTime startLdt = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-01T00:00");
LocalDateTime endLdt   = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-06-02T23:59");


LocalDate startdt = LocalDate.parse("2023-06-01");
LocalDate enddt   = LocalDate.parse("2023-06-02");

long days1 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startdt,enddt.plusDays(1));
long days2 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startLdt,endLdt.plusDays(1));
System.out.println(days1);
System.out.println(days2);

prints
2
2

